# How to ignore/remove video assistant in samsung native browser

Tags: javascript, html5-video, samsung-mobile

I need to somehow prevent my video from going full screen through samsung video assistant.

Has anyone managed to do this with javascript?

[video assistant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEZt2.png)